# Pythonic way to find elementa of a python list that are not contained in another python list

Tags: python

I am trying to find a faster solution to what I have now. My problem consists of creating a python list derived from 2 other lists. List_a has many elements, list_b has even more elements, some in common with list_a.

This is what I have:

```
list_a = [a huge python list with over 100,000 elements ]
list_b = [a huge python list with over 1,000,00 elements]
```

My solution:

```
list_c = []
for item in list_a:
    if item not in list_b:
        list_c.append(item)
```

It works, but it is very, very slow. Is there a way to solve this faster?

Comment: does order matter, do you want to keep dups and are the elements hashable?

Comment: order does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to vectorize list_a and list_b as numpy arrays, work with arrays, and then transform the resulting array back into a list. This will dramatically increase the speed of generation of list_c. Try this:

```
a = np.array(list_a)
b = np.array(list_b)
list_c = np.setdiff1d(b, a).tolist()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension

```
list_c = [item for item in list_a if item not in list_b]
```

But for performance, note that the `in` operation is faster for `set` than `list`, so you may want to add one more step first

```
set_b = set(list_b)
list_c = [item for item in list_a if item not in set_b]
```

Comment: To avoid duplicates, one can replace the `[` and `]` with `{` and `}` in newer versions of python (to make it a set).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `set` like so:

```
a = set(['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3])
b = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

print list(a.difference(b)) # prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Note that this removes all duplicates in `a` (not sure if there are duplicates they'd like to keep)

Answer (score 2):

You could use sets for this purpose:https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

```
result = (set(a) - (set(a) & set(b))
```

here `set(a) & set(b)` gives you the union of two sets/lists and `set(a) - (set(a)&set(b))` would give you all elements in a which are not in b